# DataGridView run method when clicking and unclicking a checkbox cell

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

this appears to be some pretty basic functionality but i can't find any specific examples in StackOverflow or documentation.

Checking the events for a DataGridView there doesn't appear to be anything avaliable that directly monitors for changes in a checkboxcell.

Can anyone provide an example of monitoring for a checkbox check event in datagridview then executing a method?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more of a search i found that the best way to get the changed value is to check for the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and with that trigger the edit and check the cells current value:

```
private void DataGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colReserved")
    {

        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colReserved"];

        if ((Boolean)checkCell.Value)
        {
            //Checked
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
        }
        else
        {
            //Not Checked
            MessageBox.Show("UnChecked");
        }

        DataGrid.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void DataGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGrid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        DataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```